# Get all same key/value pairs of a JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm getting a dict (well, actually, a `twitter.api.TwitterDictResponse`) which basically looks like this

```
{
    'a_list' : 
        [
            {'key': 'value1', 'foo': 'bar1'},
            {'key': 'value2', 'foo': 'bar2', 'sup': 'dope'}                
            {'key': 'value3'}
        ]
}
```

I'm interested in getting `value1`, `value2` and `value3` in a list.

I know I can do this this way :

```
output_list = []
for i in my_dict["a_list"]:
    output_list.append(i["key"])
```

But there's gotta be a more efficient way ?

Something like `my_dict["a_list"][0:3]["key"]` or something.

Comment: For starters, don't loop on the index, loop over the list *directly*.

Comment: Obviously. Edited.

Comment: So it's unclear what you mean by "efficient". The way you've show is about as efficient as you will get and it is idiomatic. You might get marginal speed gains by using a list comprehension.

Comment: Alright. The syntax is cumbersome, though. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's **not a JSON**, it is a **Python dictionary**.

You can boost performance (a bit) by using the following list comprehension:

```
output_list = [ x['key'] for x in my_dict['a_list'] ]
```

You can't do this (much) more efficiently, since you will have to loop over the elements, to obtain a list of these elements.

The only other way to do it is *lazily*, by for instance using a `map(..)`:

```
output_list = map(lambda x : x['key'],my_dict['a_list'])
```

But then you **do not generate a list**, but a **generator**. Eventually it will take the same time (if you need all the elements). But the generator is constructed fast (because the mapping is postponed).